# Is there any way where we can add shadow to the view only for left and right sides in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a card view to the rows of the section, where for the first row I want the top left and top right shadow with corner radius and the last row of the section will have the bottom left and bottom right shadow with corner radius. So in the middles rows will have only left and right shadow without corner radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it is working for me

```
yourRowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
yourRowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
yourRowView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0

let shadowRect: CGRect = imageView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 4)
yourRowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowRect).cgPath
```